# What is the minimum android api level (or min sdk) for sen/receive data using bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I want to send/receive data with bluetooth between android device and the bluetooth hardware.
What is the minimum android api level(or min sdk) for using bluetooth services?
Can i use bluetooth services in android 4 and above?

Comment: thank you for your answer . after long researching i found the best sample in this link : github.com/Sash0k/bluetooth-spp-terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, you must use min API level 5
[Read More](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.0.html#api-level)

Comment: thank you for your answer . after long researching i found the best sample in this link : https://github.com/Sash0k/bluetooth-spp-terminal

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of broad, send/receive data is not enough information,
bluetooth works on [profiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles):

if you mean send data using BT-LE or Low Energy then see matheszabi's answer.

but long back ago(Gingerbread   Ver. 2.3) that you can use Bluetooth over a SPP...